# unix how to list all of my files' extension in my homedicetory with the number of them

Tags: unix

I'm trying to solve a question, but I don't know at all help me
like this picture

[image]

Comment: which command did you use to list the files?

Comment: As this sounds a lot like homework and you didn't show any effort, I'll just give you a few tips: `man ls`, `sort` and `uniq`, and google _awk NF_ or alternatively google _bash while_ and read [this (tip: %)](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) along with `man sort` and `uniq`. Good luck!